how to rewrite import paths in angular with esbuild
I need to rewrite import paths for excluded packages
like this:
import something from "#my-module/file"

#my-module is added to externalDependencies in angular.json to be excluded from bundling
now I want to replace #my-module/* to be /my-module/*.js in the output
in nodejs (i.e. backend) I use imports{} property in dist/package.json, like this
{
  imports: {
   "#my-module/*" : "./ my-module/*.js"
 }
}

it may work (but not tested) if I replace static imports with dynamic imports, but I don't want to do that, as static imports are already being excluded from bundling as expected.
I use esbuild as builder, and Angular v17
update
I used importMap
<script type="importmap">
      {
        "imports": {
          "#my-module": "/my-module",
         }
      }
    </script>

it worked.
